# Scaling UICollectionViewCells down as more added to UICollectionView

Tags: ios, ios6, uicollectionview, autolayout, uicollectionviewcell

I am trying to work with Auto Layout to scale down some `UICollectionViewCell`s as more are added to the `UICollectionView`

I have an application which as the user types a `UICollectionViewCell` is created with the typed letter (like a tile).

[image]

At present the views begin to drop off after 5. What I would like to do is shrink both the `UICollectionViewCell` and the `UILabel` within the cell as the right edge is reached.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#pragma mark - Collection View Data Flow Layout
-(CGSize)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView layout:(UICollectionViewLayout *)collectionViewLayout sizeForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
//    NSLog(@"%s",__PRETTY_FUNCTION__);
    NSLog(@"the word array count is: %i",self.wordArray.count);
    if (self.wordArray.count <= 5) {
        return CGSizeMake(50,50);
    } else if (self.wordArray.count <= 6 ) {
        return CGSizeMake(30, 30);
    } else if (self.wordArray.count <= 8 ) {
        return CGSizeMake(10, 10);
    } else {
        return CGSizeMake(100,100);
    }
```